# Cannot find header file in Visual Studio project directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, directory-structure

I am trying to build a simple Windows 32 Console application pong game using Visual C++. See link http://www.noobtuts.com/cpp/2d-pong-game for more information. I have downloaded a group of headers files as well as a DLL file and libraries in a folder called freeglut_files.

Structure:

```
/GL
    /freeglut.h
    /freeglut.lib
    /freeglut_ext.h
    /freeglut_std.h
   /glut.h
/freeglut.dll
/freeglut.lib
```

In Visual Studio Community 2015, my project structure looks like this:

```
/Pong
    /External Dependencies
        /Contains a number of files including GL.h and GLU.h (see below)
    /Header Files
        /stdafx.h
        /targetver.h
    /Resource Files
    /Source Files
        /freeglut.dll
        /freeglut.h
        /freeglut.lib
        /freeglut_ext.h
        /freeglut_std.h
        /glut.h
        /Pong.cpp (executable)
        /stdafx.cpp
        /ReadMe.txt
```

I added all the files, including the GL directory, to the source files directory of my Visual Studio project.
For some reason Visual Studio puts some of the header files in the `/External Dependencies` folder, including GL.h and GLU.h. However, my compiler cannot seem to find freeglut.h. I have tried moving it to the `/Header Files` directory and cannot move it to the `/External Dependencies` directory. Here is my code to Pong.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include "freeglut.h"

#pragma comment (lib, "OpenGL32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler will not compile the line where I include freeglut.h. Where should this file be? Why can I not add it to `/External Dependencies`?

Comment: Try putting it into your header files directory.

Comment: "External Dependencies" is an auto-generated folder. You cannot add anything to it manually. Everything that your project files include that is not added to "Header Files", will automatically appear in "External Dependencies".

Comment: However, what you see in "Header Files" and "External Dependencies" has no importance whatsoever. The only folder that matters is "Source Files", which should contain compilable source files. You have added a lot of stuff that is not supposed to be there. `.h` have no business being in "Source Files". `.dll` and `.lib` files have no business being there either.

Comment: where would the dlls and libs go

Comment: still can't find it if it's in header files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at page *[Team Development with Visual Studio .NET and Visual SourceSafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx)*. It might help problems in the future as well. It's always good to try to find the answer from the developer of the software you're using.